# How to use Git with Magento 2 for development and deployment

Tags: magento2, git, xampp

Hello beautiful people

I started developing an ecommerce page locally and I would love to use Git in order to add another stage to the development process and be able to make changes to the page from one place and push them to the server.

Currently the server where the development is done is running Magento 2.2 CE, on Windows server with PHP 7.1.13 and the whole thing is served using xampp.

But since the server is in another floor, I am using remote desktop for making changes to magento files. So I want to develop on my machine and push whatever changes I made to the server. And when someday we go live, I would love to deploy to the production server using the setup from our current server.

How could this be approached? I am using xampp in the two local stages, but eventually the production server will be a Linux VPS.

Comment: I don't really know how to help you but i gotta say, best opening line i've seen on this website

Comment: glad you like it @John

Comment: How could this be flagged as out of topic? It has to do about remote Magento 2 development and Magento 2 essentials.

Comment: Your question seems to be primarily based on setup, rather than the debugging and programming of a Magento site, which is what this forum is primarily used for